# Windows 8.1 Laptop sound not playing through speakers

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, sound-card, speakers

My Dell Latitude 6520 is facing the following problem: sound will only play through connected headphones; no audio through speakers, once the headphones are disconnected.
I have uninstalled and re-installed the sound card driver multiple times with no result. As a side note, this laptop model has been affected by the sensor in the headphones plug; people are reporting this issue, that is, although the headphones are disconnected, the sensor will detect them, disabling playback through the speakers.
I gave up until today, once it happened something strange.
In a Skype call, audio was playing through the speakers, although the headphone was connected! How could this magic occur?
This lead to a few statements:
- speakers are not damaged, they work
- some configuration in the computer is spoiled, although in the sound properties->playback, the speakers are correctly set as the default playback device....
I wonder how could skype bypass eventually the headphone sensor or why Skype can successfully use the speakers while the system cannot.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "wiggling" the headphone jack to trick the sensor into think the headphone insert is gone. Depending on your specific build model of [Dell Latitude 6520](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19345854), you can replace just the headphone jack circuit board or worst case, have the entire motherboard replaced.

The link I referenced provides all the troubleshooting steps and ways to confirm if the sensor is the issue. The document is too long to paraphrase here.

Comment: But how does Skype use the external speakers?

Comment: I have performed the diagnostic test within the BIOS. The speakers are working correctly! Must be a Window configuration problem

Comment: Oh well the troubleshooting guide states that it could be a fialure on the sens pin.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Is your laptop still under warranty? If so, back your machine up and get it fixed with Dell.

Comment: No unfortunately! Not worth it to replace the motherboard. Thanks